# Getting images from wordpress post and showing through Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages

I've been working on a webcomic website for a while now but for a few weeks now I've been stuck on the comic viewing part.

In theory, what I'm trying to do is grab images from the WordPress post and store them in a PHP Array variable and show 1 element of the Array at a time through Javascript.

Can anyone help out?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Since many details are not mentioned I will try to answer as best as I can from whatever you have mentioned.

In case I have access to theme functions I will try to get the post attachments as array of URLs and render them wherever I want to with the help of slider to achieve one image at a time. In case I am not able to extract the post attachments I will get the url of post, get the html crawl to container which holds the post content and extract the image tags and display them where ever I want to again with the help of slider

Comment: I want to use javascript so I can have navigation buttons above and below the comic page. That way the user has a way to go through the comic pages without reloading the whole page. So I would need to grab the images through PHP and then find a way to display that element of the array through javascript.

Comment: you will render the images by iterating over the array like usual but then you will need to manage the appearance through javascript, I will recommend to use a slider with buttons and disable auto slide to get the desired effect